# Should i use many to many or one to many relationship for User reviews?

Tags: mysql, sql, relational-database, one-to-many

So here is my thought process:

If the site only asks users to rate movie in a scale from 1 to 5 than it should be many to many

However if the site allows users to enter more fields like comment, then it should be one to many because comment is customized for every user and it cannot be assigned to other users

Am i right?

Comment: A user can rate many movies.  A movie can be rated by many users.  That is many-to-many.

Comment: @GordonLinoff so should it be many to many relationship between movie and user? or should i just add a field in movie denote rating?

Comment: Can only one person, ever, rate a movie? Can each person only ever rate one movie? These are questions you need to answer, but the answers should be pretty obvious.

Comment: Its one-to-one from this perspective:  a user table, a movies table, and a ratings table.  A user can only rate a movie one time.  A movie can only have one rating per user.  A rating can only be entered by one user for one movie.

Comment: You got it all wrong. Suggest reading first https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model) and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-to-many_(data_model)

Answer (score 1):

The movie and user have a relationship to reviews and not directly to each other.

> Should i use many to many or one to many relationship for User reviews?

Therefore to answer this question it is a **zero to many** relationship from User to Review as they may have no reviews and a **zero to many** relationship from Movie to Review as it may be unreviewed. If you have business logic that requires a movie to have a review or a user to have at least one review then it can be one to many. Depending on how ambiguous your design is as per this question [erd-many-vs-zero-or-many-one-or-many-crowfoot-notation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/345709/erd-many-vs-zero-or-many-one-or-many-crowfoot-notation). The image below is an example ERD for a movie rating system and shows these relationships.

[image: ERD for movie review system]

Comment: I guess it should be "zero or many" not "zero to many".